# Отсортируйте массив так, чтобы все нули в нем оказались в конце массива, сохранив при этом порядок чисел

Tags: python, list, числа

На вход вашей программе поступает список целых чисел через пробел.

Отсортируйте массив так, чтобы все нули в нем оказались в конце массива, сохранив при этом порядок чисел.

Ввод:

Список целых чисел через пробел

Вывод:

Список чисел в котором нули находятся в конце.

Sample Input:

```
10 0 3 0 4 0 0 5 6 7 8
```

Sample Output:

```
10 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 0 0 0
```

Ничего дельного я сам не написал(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

1. подсчитать кол-во нулей в списке
2. собрать новый список без нулей
3. добавить к списку список только с нулями

**вариант 2 (в 1 строку):**

выполнить сортировку где в `key` указать функцию сравнения с `0`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: s = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]

s0 = s.count(0)

s01 = s0 * [0]

s = list(filter(lambda x: x!= 0, s))

print(s.append(s01))

вроде как все сделал, код не сработал

Comment: последний оператор неправильный

Comment: Чтобы объединить списки, используется extend или просто +

Answer (score 0):

s = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]

s0 = s.count(0)

s01 = s0 * [0]

s01 = (" ".join(map(str, s01)))

s = list(filter(lambda x: x!= 0, s))

s.append(s01)

s = (" ".join(map(str, s)))

print(s)

Comment: Оформите ответ как полагается и дополните объяснениями